# Why can't C# implicitly convert int to string?

Tags: c#, compiler, type-conversion

C# allows implicit conversions of integers to strings when used in an expression. For example, this is completely valid:

```
int myInt = 10;
string concatenatedString = "myInt is " + myInt;
string interpolatedString = $"myInt is {myInt}";
```

However, when the int is not being concatenated or interpolated, C# requires an explicit conversion.

```
int myInt = 10;
string myString = myInt; 
// compiler error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'"
```

Obviously this isn't a major pain: a simple `.ToString()` takes care of this just fine. But if .NET knows that every possible int is also a valid string, why does it still require an explicit conversion? I'd like to know what's going on in the "mind" of the compiler.

Comment: I'll post this as a comment because it is only a guess.  Concatenating strings seems pretty clear that you want the output to be a string.  It probably also leverages the fact that all `object`s have a `ToString` method and treats the `int` like an `object`.  Just assigning an `int` (or any other `object`) to a string should be possible (by calling `ToString`), which seems like most of the time would be an error.  If the compiler allowed any `object` to be assigned to a string, would you want a `MyClass` object to implicitly convert to a string without an error or warning? I wouldn't.

Comment: Your question is about `int` specifically; what is special to you about `int`?  You can add *any* expression that has a type convertible to `object` to a string. So either your question really should be "why can't C# convert `object` to `string`?" or you should say why you think that `int` is more deserving of this conversion than, say, `decimal` or `IComparable<BigInteger>` or `System.Delegate`.

Comment: `$"{myInt}"` (I'm told to add way more than 15 chars)

Comment: Have you ever been surprised when php or js do something unexpected because of implicit type casting? I think your answer likely lies there.

Comment: @RubberDuck Most of those unexpected cases are due to lossy conversions, which this one is not. (Not saying that I like this particular implicit conversion)

Comment: You're right @CodesInChaos, but once you introduce an implicit integer to string conversion, you have to suddenly deal with "What does `"1" == 1` mean? As someone who's had his fair share of parser experience, a language designer just doesn't want to deal with that and all the complexity that cascades after it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In both cases, the language is offering syntactic sugar features, rather than doing implicit casting:

```
var s = "1" + 1;
```

is converted to the [`string Concat(object, object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft(v=vs.110).aspx) method during compilation:

```
var s = String.Concat("1", 1);
```

And in the second case,

```
var i = 1;
var s = $"1={i}";
```

is converted to `string Format(string, object)` (or equivalent) method during compilation:

```
var s = string.Format("1={0}", i);
```

So in both cases, the `int` is being boxed to an `object` and each method then calls `.ToString()` on that object. No implicit casting is required.

As for the question in your title: "Why can't C# implicitly convert int to string?", the answer to that, is that neither the `String` class, not the `Int32` struct implement the `implicit operator`, so implicit conversions aren't possible between those types. You might be interested to know though that post C# 7, one feature being considered for the language is called "[Extension everything](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11159)". This would allow you to add implicit conversions between various types and strings to the language, such that you could do something like:

```
string s = 1;
```

if you really wanted to. Of course, that raises the question, would you want to?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere (before C# 6 was rolled out) that string interpolation would use a heuristic approach to choose between `String.Format` and `String.Concat`. Wasn't that implemented?

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy, I believe that string interpolation does indeed choose between a number of different approaches to implementing string interpolation. I've somewhat simplified things here in my answer. I think there are some good resources on SO on this topic, which I'll dig out if you'd like.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy, found what I was thinking of. There was much debate around how to handle cultures. By default `String.Format` is used, but you can force the interpolation down the `IFormattable` route to allow control over the interpolation. For example, [see this question and answer from (of course) Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425899/difference-between-string-formattablestring-iformattable).

Comment: The C# designers can add implicit conversions without the types overloading the `implicit operator`. I'm pretty sure the widening integer conversions were implemented that way. They could have easily chosen to add such a built-in implicit conversion from integers to strings.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common use cases for the "out-of-context" conversion of an integer to a string:

```
int myInt = 10;
string myString = myInt;
```

The first scenario creates a one-character string containing just a line-feed:

- Pretend the decimal number 10 is a character.
- Create a string containing just that character.

The second scenario creates a two-character string containing the digit "1" and the digit "0":

- Perform an integer-to-ascii conversion of the integer 10.
- Put the result in the new string.

If C# had implemented either of these alternatives, it is likely that many programmers would have written subtle bugs because they (incorrectly) assumed that the other alternative would work.